# Difference between "within" and "between" variance in multiple imputation

Tags: variance, missing-data, data-imputation, multiple-imputation

What do is **within-variance** and **between-variance**  mean in multiple imputation?

I need some illustration.

Answer (score 3):

In layman's terms, the within variance is the variance *within* each dataset on the parameters being estimated, whereas the between variance is the variance *across* datasets in those parameters.

In other words, what gets called the *within* variance in multiple imputation is just regular old error variance in analyses without multiple imputation (i.e. analyses on a single dataset). You can think of this as just the noise in your model. The between variance is how much your estimates change one imputation to another --- it's what gets added to your analysis by imputing more than one dataset.

## Toy example

To illustrate, consider a simple dataset, where we want to run a linear regression where X1 and X2 predict Y. First, we generate the data:

```
set.seed(24601)

# generate random X1 and X2, and generate Y based on them
X1 <- rnorm(10)
X2 <- rnorm(10)
Y <- .5*X1 + .5*X2 + rnorm(10)

# put missing values in X1 and X2
X1[sample(1:10, 3)] <- NA
X2[sample(1:10, 3)] <- NA

my_df <- data.frame(Y, X1, X2)
```

Here's the data (note the missing values present):

```
> round(my_df, 2)
       Y    X1    X2
1   0.56 -0.26 -0.58
2   0.08  0.58 -0.25
3  -1.31  0.47    NA
4  -0.51    NA -0.25
5   1.01 -0.27  1.33
6   0.22    NA -0.44
7  -0.54  0.26    NA
8   0.25 -0.26 -0.70
9  -0.38 -1.23  0.01
10 -0.83    NA    NA
```

Now we'll make three different datasets, each time imputing values in for the missing ones on X1 and X2. Because we'll used a probabilistic imputation (rather than a deterministic one), the values will be a little different for each dataset we impute.

```
library(Amelia) # an R package for multiple imputation
imputed_data <- amelia(my_df, m=3)
```

If you look at the imputed datasets, you'll see they differ in value for the observations that were missing (output truncated for readability):

```
> round(imputed_data$imputations$imp1, 2)
       Y    X1    X2
1   0.56 -0.26 -0.58
2   0.08  0.58 -0.25
3  -1.31  0.47 -2.01
4  -0.51 -0.53 -0.25
...
> round(imputed_data$imputations$imp2, 2)
       Y    X1    X2
1   0.56 -0.26 -0.58
2   0.08  0.58 -0.25
3  -1.31  0.47 -3.07
4  -0.51  0.10 -0.25
...
```

If we run the regression in each dataset, we'll get slightly different results because of those differences in the imputed values (output edited for readability):

```
m1 <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = imputed_data$imputations$imp1)
m2 <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = imputed_data$imputations$imp2)
m3 <- lm(Y ~ X1 + X2, data = imputed_data$imputations$imp3)

> summary(m1)
...
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   0.1897     0.2018   0.940   0.3784  
X1            0.1427     0.3433   0.416   0.6901  
X2            0.6809     0.2231   3.051   0.0185 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4947 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.606, Adjusted R-squared:  0.4935 
F-statistic: 5.384 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.03839

> summary(m2)
...
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)   0.2369     0.1814   1.306   0.2329  
X1            0.1601     0.3293   0.486   0.6416  
X2            0.4839     0.1399   3.460   0.0106 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.4548 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.6671,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.5719 
F-statistic: 7.012 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.0213

> summary(m3)
...
Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)  -0.1121     0.2386  -0.470    0.653
X1           -0.3529     0.4672  -0.755    0.475
X2            0.2467     0.4406   0.560    0.593

Residual standard error: 0.7348 on 7 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.1308,    Adjusted R-squared:  -0.1176 
F-statistic: 0.5266 on 2 and 7 DF,  p-value: 0.6123
```

In the above results, you can see that each model has variance around its estimates (the standard errors for each regression coefficient).

To get an estimate of the *within* variance for the effect of X1, you could average all of the SEs for X1 across the three models (and likewise for X2). To get an estimate of the *between* variance, you'd want to look at how much the coefficients for X1 and X2 vary across the three imputations. 
This is exactly what is often done to calculate SEs for multiple imputation[1]: You average the SEs from each of the datasets to get the "within" variance, and then measure the variability in the coefficients across datasets to get the "between" variance, and combine them together into a single estimate that reflects both the natural noise in the data and the uncertainty due to the "guessing" done to fill in missing data during the multiple imputation process.

[1] more specifically, this is a brief description of [Rubin's rules from his 1987 book *Multiple Imputation for Nonresponse in Surveys*](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/store/10.1002/9780470316696.fmatter/asset/fmatter.pdf;jsessionid=356357752D4F83D723180B6472BCEB37.f04t01?v=1&t=jcij54fr&s=b1dc4ab220539dfdc321a0653a0645525caac039))

Comment: @ whitin varinace: Accordning to [this book](https://bookdown.org/mwheymans/bookmi/rubins-rules.html#pooling-standard-errors) we can not simply take the avarage of the SEs. Compare formula 9.2.

Answer (score 0):

You can think of the within-variance $W$ and between-variance $B$ in multiple imputation as the between and within groups variation in [ANOVA](https://people.richland.edu/james/lecture/m170/ch13-1wy.html) but the total variance $T$ is NOT equal to the sum of the within-variance and between-variance( $T \neq W+B$ )that would be correct only if we have infinite number of imputations $m$ i.e ($T_{\infty} = W_{\infty}+B_{\infty}$)so that we have to modify the latter equation to let the multiple imputation work with low values of $m$ and since in multiple imputation our estimate $\bar\theta$ is a combined estimate of the estimates stem from the $m's$ repeated imputation and the imputed values are sampled form a distribution reflect our uncertainty about the missing values which is the posterior predictive distribution this implies we can add a simulation variance term such that $T = W+B+B/{\infty}$ so that $B$ approximate $B_{\infty}$ so in summary we have three sources of variance :

1. Within variance which is the conventional statistical measure of variability
2. Between variance  caused by the missing values
3. $B/{\infty}$ simulation variance .